# Asp.Net Master page changes in design changes related C# files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am working on a asp.net webforms application where I updated web page design in master page. There are no changes to .master.cs, .master.designer.cs.

But When I tried check in in the code,  .master.cs, .master.designer.cs are also shown in the updated files list. I tried comparing files but there are no changes in cs files code.

My question is: I f I have to deploy the changes to live server, should I deploy only Masterpage.Master or also the cs files linked to Master page?

Comment: If there are no changes to the files, then you can use "Undo" to remove them from the pending changes list. Or you can check in the changes, since they aren't really changes, they won't affect anything except your source control history.

Comment: You don't deploy .cs files to an ASP.NET site.  If you do, you are exposing your code.

Comment: I mean the dlls instead of .cs files. Should I deploy dlls also related to master page?

Comment: You would have to take a copy of your Masterpage that is already deployed and modify it. Then copy it back to your live site.

Comment: I have same issue, no changes i see on live website. any suggestion ?